# I have installed LAMP SERVER IN UBUNTU 13,04 .But could not login to phpmyadmin

Tags: lamp

I have installed LAMP SERVER IN UBUNTU 13,04 .But could not login to phpmyadmin,showing the error message #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server,  and Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

This will prompt you for a new password.  If that doesn't work try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root mysql
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('New_Password') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

<sup>Source:MySQL RM</sup>